# Display number of item in the cart if %d > 0 else display %d

Tags: php, cart

I'm working on a website

> http://mtcdistrup.cluster003.ovh.net/

and I'm facing a problem. I'd like to display number of items in the cart over an image. I found a way for this, but now the problem is that I want to display it only if the number of item is not null.

I'm using Wordpress and woocomerce. So I found this to display number of item in the cart :

```
<?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '<h6>%d<h6> ', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?>
```

and I want to use this  in a kind of way, mix both to do my thing :

```
<?php
if (%d > 0)
{
    echo "<h6>%d<h6>";
}
else
{
    echo" ";
}
?>
```

I really have no idea about if I'm doing it correctly or not. So let me know how can I mix both of them in the best way.

Thanks a lot in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case `$d` is not a variable but thing that says 'Hi, here will be an integer (read from arguments) displayed as a decimal number'. Then `sprintf` parse string and "replace" `$d` with `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) you can read more about `sprintf` and formating.

In your case you need to use `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`. I don't know how would your code look like because I don't use wordpress. Anyway I think that information about what exactly is `$d` and information that you will use `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` should be enough to solve your problem.